# Пояснения по bash скрипту

Tags: linux, файлы, bash

> Копирование группы файлов удовлетворяющих маске из одного каталога в два других (копировать подкаталоги). Маска и два других каталога передаются как параметры пакетного файла.

Есть задача и соответственно код для ее решения. Но есть несколько вопросов:

1. Как сократить этот код? Я более чем уверен, что 2 последние строки можно сократить, но у меня не получилось
2. Что значит `-print0` в сочетании с `-0`? Везде написано, что это для того, чтобы можно было обрабатывать кавычки и пробелы в именах, но почему тогда при запуске скрипта он вообще не видит имена?
3. За что отвечает `-t`?
4. Как ко всему этому добавить вывод файлов, которые копируем? Для find вроде как есть опция `-print`, но она почему-то тут не работает

Вот скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

dest1=$(realpath "$3") &&
dest2=$(realpath "$4") &&
cd "$1" &&
find -name "*.$2" -print0 |
xargs -0r cp --parents -t "${dest1}" --

find -name "*.$2" -print0 |
xargs -0r cp --parents -t "${dest2}" --
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Как сократить этот код? Я более чем уверен, что 2 последние строки
>   можно сократить, но у меня не получилось

Вряд ли получится избавиться от них, поскольку в задаче требуется два копирования. Очевидных путей для сокращения кода я тут не вижу.

> 2) Что значит `-print0` в сочетании с `-0`? Везде написано, что это для
>   того, чтобы можно было обрабатывать кавычки и пробелы в именах, но
>   почему тогда при запуске скрипта он вообще не видит имена?

Имена файлов в Linux представляют собой произвольную бесконечную* последовательность ***байт*** (!), в которой не встречаются нулевой байт `'\0'` (зарезервирован) и наклонная черта - слеш (используется для разделения имён каталогов в пути файла). Стоит отметить, что понятие *байт* не тождественно понятию *символ*.

Действие `-print0` заставляет утилиту **find** печатать имена файлов, разделяя их нулевым байтом (т.е. такой, который в пути заведомо не встретится). Параметр `-0` говорит утилите **xargs** интерпретировать нулевой байт как разделитель для аргументов вызываемой команды (в примере **cp**).

* где бесконечность равна 255 байтам. Или более точнее [_PC_NAME_MAX](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pathconf). По идее ограничение можно обойти, пересобрав ядро.

> 3) За что отвечает `-t`?

Это параметр для **cp** указывает куда копировать входные файлы. Замечу, что параметр принимает один аргумент — путь к каталогу. Из-за этого двойной минус не может быть сразу после `-t`. Но эти минусы следует ставить, чтобы утилита **cp** прекратила дальнейшую обработку параметров, ради безопасности.

> 4) Как ко всему этому добавить вывод файлов, которые копируем? Для
>   **find** вроде как есть опция `-print`, но она почему-то тут не работает

Так не получается, потому что вывод **find** направлен на ввод **xargs**. Но можно попросить **xargs** напечатать выполняемую команду с помощью флага `-t`. Или чуть усложнить команду для **xargs**:

```
... | xargs -0ri sh -c "echo '{}'; cp -t $dest2 -- '{}'"
```

Правда, в в этом случае дела с экранированием обстоят из рук вон плохо, да и с производительностью тоже не ах-ти.

В принципе, можно воспользоваться утилитой **tee**, воткнув её между **find** и **xargs**. Если устраивает вывод в файл. Или же поизвращаться с перенаправлениями в **bash**.